# how to turn off automatic generation on my Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I used EF codefirst. My domain models were list below:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        BookType = new BookType();
        BookPlace = new BookPlace();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publishment { get; set; }
    public int BookTypeID { get; set; }
    public int BookPlaceID { get; set; }

    public BookType BookType { get; set; }
    public BookPlace BookPlace { get; set; }
}

public class BookType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookPlace
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

And Here were my doamin mapper:

```
public class BookMapper:EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public BookMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("Book");

        this.HasKey(c => c.ID);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Author).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(c => c.Author).IsOptional();

        this.Property(c => c.Publishment).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(c => c.Publishment).IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(c => c.BookType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.BookTypeID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        this.HasRequired(c => c.BookPlace).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.BookPlaceID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}

public class BookTypeMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<BookType>
{
    public BookTypeMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("BookType");

        this.HasKey(c => c.ID);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}

public class BookPlaceMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<BookPlace>
{
    public BookPlaceMapper()
    {
        this.ToTable("BookPlace");

        this.HasKey(c=>c.ID);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(c => c.ID).IsRequired();

        this.Property(c => c.Position).IsRequired();
        this.Property(c => c.Position).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

And here was my BookContext:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public BookContext()
        : base("BookConnection")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BookContext, BookContextMConfig>());
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookType> BookTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookPlace> BookPlaces { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookMapper());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookTypeMapper());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookPlaceMapper());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Here was my IRepository interface and Repository class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    T GetByID(long id);
    T GetByID(int id);
    T GetByID(Guid id);
    T GetByID(string id);
    T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
}

public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private IDbContext context;

    private IDbSet<T> dbset;
    public virtual IDbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (dbset == null)
                dbset = context.Set<T>();
            return dbset;
        }
    }

    ...   

    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("实体类为空");
            DbSet.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbex)
        {
            var msg = string.Empty;
            foreach(var validationErrors in dbex.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach(var validateionError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    msg+=string.Format("Property:{0} Error:{1}",validateionError.PropertyName,validateionError.ErrorMessage);

            var fail = new Exception(msg,dbex);
            throw fail;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem was: Every time when I tried to add book data to database, the Insert method in Repository.cs class would throw me an exception as : Position value in BookPlace table is   required. Name  value in BookType table is required.

I didn't know why and which caused this, would anyone give me some suggest on this? thx.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by doing below:

Change Book model as below:

```
public class Book
{

public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Author { get; set; }
public string Publishment { get; set; }
public int BookTypeID { get; set; }
public int BookPlaceID { get; set; }

public virtual BookType BookType { get; set; }
public virtual BookPlace BookPlace { get; set; }
}
```